# style and theme support for lower APIs

Tags: android, android-styles, android-api-levels

The following

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
</style>
```

works fine but the following

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
</style>
```

requires API level 16.

Now i am confused, am i just hiding the error by removing `android:` prefix or will this work fine on android 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's consider how attributes work in a layout. If you're using the support library to handle font families, you'd write something like this:

```
<TextView
    app:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
    .../>
```

If, on the other hand, you were using the framework API (which only exists on API 16+), you'd write this:

```
<TextView
    android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
    .../>
```

---

When you're creating styles, anything that would have used the `app:` namespace in a layout simply doesn't get any namespace at all. So a style specifying

```
<item name="fontFamily">
```

would correspond to the first example above, while a style specifying

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">
```

would correspond to the second example above.

Whichever one you choose to use should be guided by this principle. If you're using the support library, then dropping the namespace is a good thing to do. If you're not using the support library, then dropping the namespace is a bad thing to do.

**tl;dr**: Dropping the namespace is a good idea in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know the difference.  i thought i had to set fonts in code with typeface